# ViewModel issue

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress, viewmodel

I need pop up a window which takes time. The button is in Pressed state until the new window is opened. Hence I want to add a wait indicator over the UI window after I click the button and before the the  window opens. The code of ViewModel is correct because I referred to a sample code. But why there is no response after I click the button.

The project file URL

https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/attachment/file/5268961b-ce35-4e40-b7c1-e33bffab902b

MainWindow:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using DevExpress.Xpf.Core;

namespace WaitIndicatorDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : DXWindow
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vm = new MainVM();
            DataContext = vm;
        }

        MainVM vm;

        private void buttonShow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vm.IsBusy = !vm.IsBusy;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewMode:

```
    using DevExpress.Mvvm;

namespace WaitIndicatorDemo
{
    public class MainVM
    {
        private readonly ISplashScreenService _waitIndicatorService;

        public virtual bool IsBusy { get; set; }

        public MainVM()
        {
            _waitIndicatorService = 
                ServiceContainer.Default.GetService<ISplashScreenService>("WaitIndicatorService");
        }

        protected void OnIsBusyChanged()
        {
            if (IsBusy)
                _waitIndicatorService.ShowSplashScreen();
            else
                _waitIndicatorService.HideSplashScreen();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the XAML, the comment ones are the original sample code. The checkbox bind to IsBusy. The indicator pop up when the checkbox is checked. I now want to pop up after press the button.

```
    <dx:DXWindow x:Class="WaitIndicatorDemo.MainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
             xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm"
             xmlns:waitIndicatorDemo="clr-namespace:WaitIndicatorDemo"
             xmlns:dxe="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/editors"
             WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
               Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
             <!--DataContext="{dxmvvm:ViewModelSource Type=waitIndicatorDemo:MainVM}"-->
             <!--Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">-->

    <Grid Margin="10">
        <!--<dxe:CheckEdit Content="Is Busy" IsChecked="{Binding IsBusy}" 
                       VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

        <Button Content="Button1" IsEnabled ="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={dxmvvm:BooleanNegationConverter}}"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click"/>

        <Button Content="Button2" IsEnabled="{Binding IsBusy, Converter={dxmvvm:BooleanNegationConverter}}"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>-->
        <Button x:Name="buttonShow" Content="Show"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" Margin="50,70,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="buttonShow_Click" />

    </Grid>
</dx:DXWindow>
```

Comment: Is `OnIsBusyChanged` getting called? Did you set that in your xaml?

Comment: Doesn't the value of vm.IsBusy  change automatically call the OnIsBusyChanged()?

Comment: @selfay No, the method `OnIsBusyChanged` won't get called magically, you'll have to call it yourself in your `IsBusy` setter. Note that some tools will do that magic for you, like Fody, but I suggest you start by understanding the flow before trying to automate things.

Comment: @ Roger Leblanc @Chronicle Thank you. You are right. I change protected void OnIsBusyChanged() to public and call it. It works. But strange that why in sample code can work without calling it.

Comment: @selfay The DevExpress sample code is probably using [POCOViewModel](https://community.devexpress.com/blogs/wpf/archive/2013/12/03/devexpress-mvvm-framework-introduction-to-poco-viewmodels.aspx) attribute in order to generate some magical code that adds boilerplate code. As said before, magical code is great when you understand what it does for you, but you first need to take the long road to fully understand what's happening behind the curtains before trying to use attributes like `POCOViewModel`.

Comment: @selfay Just a heads up, I've looked at the sample code you share in my answer below, the reason why `OnIsBusyChanged` is being called in the sample and not in your code is because the sample is declaring the `DataContext` in XAML using `dxmvvm:ViewModelSource`, which will convert any type of class into a `POCO`, which adds the magical boilerplate. As you decided to remove (comment) this declaration in your code and declare it directly in code behind, you are not using a `POCO` anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in your code sample :
1- The method `OnIsBusyChanged` in your ViewModel is never called.
2- Your XAML doesn't declare any `ISplashScreenService` object in the Window behaviors, like a `DXSplashScreenService` for instance.

Here's how you can fix both of those issues.

First, fix the ViewModel.

```
public class MainVM
{
    private readonly ISplashScreenService _waitIndicatorService;

    private bool _isBusy;
    public virtual bool IsBusy 
    {
        get
        {
            return _isBusy;
        }

        set
        {
            _isBusy = value;
            OnIsBusyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainVM()
    {
        _waitIndicatorService = 
            ServiceContainer.Default.GetService<ISplashScreenService>("WaitIndicatorService");
    }

    protected void OnIsBusyChanged()
    {
        _waitIndicatorService.SetSplashScreenState("Doing some work...");

        if (IsBusy)
            _waitIndicatorService.ShowSplashScreen();
        else
            _waitIndicatorService.HideSplashScreen();
    }
}
```

Then, your XAML.

```
<dx:DXWindow x:Class="WaitIndicatorDemo.MainWindow"
    <!-- ... -->
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <dx:DXSplashScreenService x:Name="WaitIndicatorService">
            <dx:DXSplashScreenService.ViewTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="LightGray" CornerRadius="5">
                            <Border BorderBrush="#FF0072C6" BorderThickness="1" Margin="15" CornerRadius="5">
                                <Grid>
                                    <ProgressBar BorderThickness="0" Value="{Binding Progress}" Maximum="{Binding MaxProgress}" IsIndeterminate="{Binding IsIndeterminate}" Height="12" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding State, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </dx:DXSplashScreenService.ViewTemplate>
        </dx:DXSplashScreenService>
    </dxmvvm:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Grid Margin="10">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid>
</dx:DXWindow>
```

This code was mainly taken from the [How to: Use DxSplashScreenService sample](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-use-dxsplashscreenservice-e4858).

Comment: Thank you Roger. I used below URL example. But I am now stuck at how to make the indicator in the middle of the UI window or in the middle of screen. I didn't find any place to set the state.  https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t449969/wait-indicator-shown-over-the-window

Comment: @selfay In `App.xaml`, add `SplashScreenStartupLocation="CenterOwner"` inside the `DXSplashScreenService` tag (line 7).

Comment: Perfect! It is working. Thank you very much. Roger! Have a nice day!